# How to play wait music while concurrently making an api call in Twilio Voice?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, twilio, twilio-api

I am trying to create a flask python app that uses Twilio. I am wondering if there is a way that I can leverage the Twilio library to play wait music while making an API call.

Currently:

```
import requests as pyreq

@app.route('/get_response', methods=['POST'])
def get_response():
    response = VoiceResponse()
    reply = pyreq.get("https://XXXXXXXXXXXXX")
    data = reply.json()
    response.say(data)
    response.say(' Goodbye!',  voice = 'Polly.Olivia-Neural')
    response.hangup()
    return str(response)
```

I want to be able to play wait music while running `reply = pyreq.get("https://XXXXXXXXXXXXX")`. Any advice on how I may be able to accomplish this?

I have tried using python threading to do this but I can't seem to figure out the right order of actions to accomplish this.

Comment: How long does the api take to return a response? You might get where you want by putting the caller in a hold queue using Twilio's Enqueue verb, setting the waitURL to the music you want to play, then when your API returns the data, redirect the call that is holding to new Twiml that says the audio.

Comment: The API takes about 10 sec

Comment: Twilio will wait about 12 seconds for Twiml before disconnecting with an error. The Enqueue option I gave you will consume maybe 5 or 6 seconds with the transfers and the connecting. The caller wouldn't hear much of the hold message. Any chance you could get the API response time down to 3 or 4 seconds?